# When I am importing the decision table in the decision table asset. I am getting back slash before the double quotation in drl file. How to fix it?

Tags: drools, jbpm

Below is my decision table(see Decision table screenshot). I have conditions in each rule. And I am having a double quotation for string datatype value. I am getting back slash before double quotation in the drl view after importing the decision table in the decision table asset in the drools workbench. How to resolve this issue. I appreciate any help you can provide.

[image: Decision table]

Below is the screenshot of the drl file image after importing the decision table.

[image: Screenshot of IDE]

I am expecting this result without backslash.

```
when
   sanctionData: Sanction(dateOfBirth=="23-02-1999")
```

Comment: Posting screenshots of the decision table is ok since they're xlsx files. Posting screenshots of code (DRL) is not. Please copy the code itself into your question.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the double quotes (") into single quotes (') in the desicion